# Is there a way to sort a FractalCollection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 and Fractal for my API.

I create a FractalCollection that needs sorting as the data that needs to be sorted on is only calculated during the transformation, so I can't sort earlier using Eloquent. The FractalCollection has no sort method on it.

```
    $fractal = new Manager();

    $paginatorAdapter = new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginator);

    $resource = new FractalCollection($paginator, new PropertiesTransformer);

    // ***** How do I now sort the FractalCollection  ****

    $resource->setPaginator($paginatorAdapter);

    return $fractal->createData($resource)->toJson();
```